# async/await in Angular `ngOnInit`

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, observable

I’m currently evaluating the pros ‘n’ cons of replacing Angular’s resp. RxJS’ `Observable` with plain `Promise` so that I can use `async` and `await` and get a more intuitive code style.

One of our typical scenarios: Load some data within `ngOnInit`. Using `Observables`, we do:

```
ngOnInit () {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(data => {
    this.data = this.modifyMyData(data);
  });
}
```

When I return a `Promise` from `getData()` instead, and use `async` and `await`, it becomes:

```
async ngOnInit () {
  const data = await this.service.getData();
  this.data = this.modifyMyData(data);
}
```

Now, obviously, Angular will not “know”, that `ngOnInit` has become `async`. I feel that this is not a problem: My app still works as before. But when I look at the `OnInit` interface, the function is obviously not declared in such a way which would suggest that it can be declared `async`:

```
ngOnInit(): void;
```

So -- bottom line: Is it reasonable what I’m doing here? Or will I run into any unforseen problems?

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17420#issuecomment-316686064) in [issue 17420](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17420): "it's not a problem for someone to use `async ngOnInit`, it is just an awkward/not recommended coding practice."

Comment: @ConnorsFan I’ve actually read **exactly** this issue before opening my post :-) (should have linked it). I am still not sure, whether “awkward” and “not recommended” have any objective reasons, or whether the Angular team just wants to push towards the reactive style?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37364973/1009922) is another good read on this subject.

Comment: @qqilihq - Hi, I'm looking at doing this conversion just now. Did you go ahead with it and were you happy with the outcome? Any issues...?

Comment: @LeeGunn It’s a so-so. I used it here and there, but all in all very sparingly. Reason (a) being the error handling (explained in detail below by @Reactgular), (b) code gets a little less “nested” (no callbacks), but the gain is quite small, and (c) we’re working with several “real” Observables in the codebase (which continuously update) -- there `await` will not help, and we’d end up with two inconsistent ways (or confuse new team members).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It is no different than what you had before.  `ngOnInit` will return a Promise and the caller will ignore that promise.  This means that the caller will not wait for everything in your method to finish before it proceeds.  In this specific case it means the view will finish being configured and the view may be launched before `this.data` is set.

That is the same situation you had before.  The caller would not wait for your subscriptions to finish and would possibly launch the app before `this.data` had been populated.  If your view is relying on `data` then you likely have some kind of `ngIf` setup to prevent you from accessing it.

I personally don't see it as awkward or a bad practice as long as you're aware of the implications.  However, the `ngIf` can be tedious (they would be needed in either way).  I have personally moved to using route resolvers where it makes sense so I can avoid this situation.  The data is loaded before the route finishes navigating and I can know the data is available before the view is ever loaded.

Comment: Thank you for mentionning route resolvers. I think it is a better approach to this problem that occurs very often.

Comment: "In this specific case it means the view will finish being configured and the view may be launched before `this.data` is set." - this is the key I think, and it's not obvious unless you think about it, and is likely to be even less obvious to future developers who are trying to maintain your code.

For this reason I would agree with the comment referenced above that this is in fact "awkward" and "bad practice".

Answer (score 43):

> Now, obviously, Angular will not “know”, that ngOnInit has become async. I feel that this is not a problem: My app still works as before.

Semantically it will compile fine and run as expected, but the convenience of writing `async / wait` comes at a cost of error handling, and I think it should be avoid.

Let's look at what happens.

What happens when a promise is rejected:

```js
public ngOnInit() {
    const p = new Promise((resolver, reject) => reject(-1));
}
```

The above generates the following stack trace:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): -1
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.js:3942:17 [angular]
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:876) [angular]
    at ExampleComponent.ngOnInit (example.component.ts:44) [angular]
    .....
```

We can clearly see that the unhandled error was triggered by a `ngOnInit` and also see which source code file to find the offending line of code.

What happens when we use `async/wait` that is reject:

```js
    public async ngOnInit() {
        const p = await new Promise((resolver, reject) => reject());
    }
```

The above generates the following stack trace:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.js:3942:17 [angular]
    at rejected (tslib.es6.js:71) [angular]
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.js:4090:36 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680) [angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559) [<root>]
```

What happened? We have no clue, because the stack trace is outside of the component.

Still, you might be tempted to use promises and just avoid using `async / wait`. So let's see what happens if a promise is rejected after a `setTimeout()`.

```js
    public ngOnInit() {
        const p = new Promise((resolver, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => reject(), 1000);
        });
    }
```

We will get the following stack trace:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.js:3942:17 [angular]
    at :4200/app-module.js:21450:30 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680) [angular]
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2650) [<root>]
```

Again, we've lost context here and don't know where to go to fix the bug.

Observables suffer from the same side effects of error handling, but *generally* the error messages are of *better* quality. If someone uses `throwError(new Error())` the *Error* object will contain a stack trace, and if you're using the `HttpModule` the *Error* object is usually a *Http response* object that tells you about the request.

So the moral of the story here: Catch your errors, use observables when you can and don't use `async ngOnInit()`, because it will come back to haunt you as a difficult bug to find and fix.

Comment: The missing part here is how would the stacktrace look when the error happens in the `Observable` are they any better?

Comment: @Peter most observables that throw an error are usually from `HttpClient` and are asynchronous. So when the error is thrown the stacktrace will be from outside of your source code. You can use the `catchError()` operator to handle errors, and if you just want stacktrace help, then  `catchError(err => throwError(err))` would rethrow the error and add your source code to the call stack.

Answer (score 14):

I wonder what are the downsides of an [immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) :

```
    ngOnInit () {
      (async () => {
        const data = await this.service.getData();
        this.data = this.modifyMyData(data);
      })();
    }
```

It is the only way I can imagine to make it work without declaring `ngOnInit()` as an `async` function

Comment: but this is as good as having a separate async function and calling it within ngOnInit


ngOnInit () {
      this.fetchData();
    }

private async fetchData(){
        const data = await this.service.getData();
        this.data = this.modifyMyData(data);
}

Comment: @ABajpai , yes, but without having a separate `async function` and without making `ngOninit() async`, which is what the user seemed to ask for.

Comment: it is the same thing as just running the promise without await, it will work, but not wait for it to finish

Answer (score 6):

`ngOnInit` [does NOT wait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39492163/271450) for the promise to complete. You can make it an async function if you feel like using await like so:

```js
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

async ngOnInit(): Promise<any> {
  const data = await firstValueFrom(this.service.getData());
  this.data = this.modifyMyData(data);
}
```

However, if you're using `ngOnInit` instead of the constructor to wait for a function to complete, you're basically doing the equivalent of this:

```js
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor() {
  firstValueFrom(this.service.getData())
    .then((data => {;
      this.data = this.modifyMyData(data);
    });
}
```

It will run the async function, but it WILL NOT wait for it to complete. If you notice sometimes it completes and sometimes it doesn't, it really just depends on the timing of your function.

Using the ideas from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065783/271450), you can basically run outside `zone.js`. `NgZone` does not include `scheduleMacroTask`, but `zone.js` is imported already into angular.

## Solution

```js
import { isObservable, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

declare const Zone: any;

async waitFor<T>(prom: Promise<T> | Observable<T>): Promise<T> {
  if (isObservable(prom)) {
    prom = firstValueFrom(prom);
  }
  const macroTask = Zone.current
    .scheduleMacroTask(
      `WAITFOR-${Math.random()}`,
      () => { },
      {},
      () => { }
    );
  return prom.then((p: T) => {
    macroTask.invoke();
    return p;
  });
}
```

I personally put this function in my `core.module.ts`, although you can put it anywhere.

Use it like so:

```js
constructor(private cm: CoreModule) { 
  const p = this.service.getData();
  this.post = this.cm.waitFor(p);
}
```

You could also check for [isBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893433/271450) to keep your observable, or wait for results.

Conversely, you could also import `angular-zen` and use it like in [this post](https://dev.to/meldiron/appwrite-with-angular-ssr-ph), although you will be importing more than you need.

J

**UPDATE: 2/26/22** - Now uses `firstValueFrom` since `.toPromise()` is depreciated.

Comment: async ngOnInit(): Promise<any> did the trick for me.

Comment: Febuary 2022 and `Observable.toPromise()` [is now deprecated](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise). Working in Angular 13 and using SSR/prerendering I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345373/2528639) to be fully featured and work out of the box.

Comment: @Rob Hall - I updated it to use `firstValueFrom`, as that is the new version.  Sometimes you should use `lastValueFrom` instead. The recommended solution you listed is extremely complicated. My version is simplified. - J

Comment: @jonathan agreed. That version also requires injection so it is not as straight forward to work into an existing algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

I used try catch inside the ngOnInit():

```
async ngOnInit() {      
   try {           
       const user = await userService.getUser();
    } catch (error) {           
        console.error(error);       
    }    
}
```

Then you get a more descriptive error and you can find where the bug is

Answer (score 3):

You can use rxjs function `of`.

```
of(this.service.getData());
```

Converts the promise to an observable sequence.

Comment: Thanks. But my goal was to avoid Observable in favor of the `await` syntax (I've grown a strong aversion against callback-based syntax, back in the days :-) ).

Comment: @qqilihq i agree, `Promise` was ugly, then we got `await` and `async` and i was happy, now we have `Observable` and we are back to ugly but more useful than `Promise`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to this question is to use [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) feature of Angular. With Resolve, your component will not be rendered until you tell it to render.

From docs:

> Interface that classes can implement to be a data provider. A data
> provider class can be used with the router to resolve data during
> navigation. The interface defines a resolve() method that is invoked
> when the navigation starts. The router waits for the data to be
> resolved before the route is finally activated.

Comment: Resolvers are a concept to consider, but they’re not a silver bullet. There are situations where `onInit` is desirable. (e.g. less code scattering, showing a loading indicator in the target view, …)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this a bit differently, you don't show your html template, but I'm assuming you're doing something in there with data, i.e.

```
<p> {{ data.Name }}</p> <!-- or whatever -->
```

Is there a reason you're not using the async pipe?, i.e.

```
<p> {{ (data$ | async).Name }}</p>
```

or

```
<p *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data"> {{ data.name }} </p>
```

and in your `ngOnInit`:

```
data$: Observable<any>; //change to your data structure
ngOnInit () {
  this.data$ = this.service.getData().pipe(
    map(data => this.modifyMyData(data))
  );
}
```