# Loading controller await problem with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

In my ngOnInit page I call a function to present a Loading and then call my service to load data.
The problem is that the service call ends before the loading starts.
How is it possibile with await?

```
loading: any;
...
ngOnInit() { 
    this.presentLoading();
    this.myService.get().subscribe((item)=>{
      console.log('dismiss');
      this.loading.dismiss();
    }, ()=>{
      this.loading.dismiss();
    })
  }

  async presentLoading() {
    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Loading...',
      duration: 20000
    });
    console.log('presentLoading')
    await this.loading.present();
  }
```

In console i can see:

```
dismiss
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined....
presentLoading
```

I’m using Ionic4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case (based on the code) you have presentLoading function that returns a promise (async), so even though inside of it you are using await statements - inside the ngOnInit hook nothing instructs execution to await for the presentLoading.

You could do:

```
  async ngOnInit() { 
    await this.presentLoading();
    this.myService.get().subscribe((item)=>{
      console.log('dismiss');
      this.loading.dismiss();
    }, ()=>{
      this.loading.dismiss();
    })
  }
```

Also since you are using Onservables it may makes sense to call dismiss inside "completed" function:

```
  async ngOnInit() { 
    await this.presentLoading();
    this.myService.get().subscribe((item)=>{
      console.log('dismiss');
    }, (error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    }, (completed)=>{
      this.loading.dismiss();
    }
  })
```

A note - making ngOnInit an async method does not "hurt", but its best to know a bit more waht implications it has: [async/await in Angular `ngOnInit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092083/async-await-in-angular-ngoninit)