# Find item index in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have delete function which will emit socket.io then socket update other party items list and remove this item (replace static text) the problem is when I receive socket data I cannot find match item to update it.

## Logic

1. User 1 delete message
2. User 2 get (static text) such as `this message was deleted`

## Flow

1. `User 1` delete message (works)
2. Message gets deleted for `User 1` (works)
3. `socket.io` gets inform of this delete (works)
4. `User 2` gets deleted message data from `socket.io` (works)
5. `socket.io` find and replace deleted message (not work)

## Code

`User 1 delete message`

```
async presentPopover(ev: any, indexOfelement: any, own: any) {

    // send clicked item data to popover (popover will delete it and send back results)
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: MessagesComponent,
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      event: ev,
      componentProps: { id: ev, index: indexOfelement, from: 'pchat', own },
      translucent: true
    });

    // returned results from popover
    popover.onDidDismiss().then((result: object) => {
      console.log('res2021 1: ', result);
      console.log('this.room.messages 2: ', this.room.messages);
      if (result['data']) {
          this.socket.emit('messageDelete', { message: result['data'] }); // data is "id: 187, index: 15"
          this.room.messages.splice(result['data'].index, 1); // remove message from user 1 list (prefered if replace the text as well here instead of removing it)
      }
    });
    return await popover.present();
}
```

`(popover)`

```
// delete message (in popover)
Pdelete(event) {
    this.privateChatsService.deleteMessage(this.navParams.get('id')).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.popoverController.dismiss({ id: this.navParams.get('id'), index: this.navParams.get('index') }); //send back data
    });
}
```

`User 2 gets update about deleted message`

```
ngOnInit() {
    // remove deleted message
    this.socket.fromEvent('messDel').subscribe((message: any) => {
        console.log('from del emit in private chat: ', message); // data is "id: 187, index: 15"
        this.room.messages.splice(message.msg.message.index, 1); // make changes in deleted item ("index" cannot be found)
    });
    // end of socket.io
}
```

**Note:** Problem is in `this.room.messages.splice(message.msg.message.index, 1);` code where socket cannot find correct item based on the index the rest is working just fine.

Comment: do you get any error message ?

Comment: @RachidO beside that `index` is undefined no.

Comment: You have `ngOninit` tagged with `async` which [can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092083/async-await-in-angular-ngoninit). Additionally you have the callback for `this.socket.fromEvent('messDel')` as async, yet aren't doing any awaiting inside. You'll need to wrap your functions/logic to actually do work with promises for that to work.

Comment: @Phix you're right this async's were for old codes when I changed them I forgot to remove async's, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved

In regard to

> this.room.messages.splice(result['data'].index, 1); // remove message from user 1 list (**prefered if replace the text as well here instead of removing it**)

I've added extra object to my response from popover to update my list items instead of remove them

```
Pdelete(event) {
    this.privateChatsService.deleteMessage(this.navParams.get('id')).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.popoverController.dismiss({ id: this.navParams.get('id'), index: this.navParams.get('index'), deleted_at: res.data.deleted_at });
    });
  }
```

Added `deleted_at` because that's what I check in HTML in order to show placeholder text.

Then for finding my correct item I've changed my socket listener to:

```
this.socket.fromEvent('messDel').subscribe((message: any) => {
      this.room.messages.find(item => item.id == message.msg.message.id).deleted_at = message.msg.message.deleted_at;
});
```

I find the item `id` based on popover response id, then I update `deleted_at` value so it can show placeholder text.

Also for `User 1` who deleted this message I did same code as socket listener therefore message doesn't get removed from his/her list, instead shows placeholder text

```
// returned results from popover
popover.onDidDismiss().then((result: object) => {
      if (result['data']) {
        this.socket.emit('messageDelete', { message: result['data'] });
        this.room.messages.find(item => item.id == result['data'].id).deleted_at = result['data'].deleted_at;
      }
});
```