# Pass subscribe response to variable - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i trying to pass the subscribe response of my **Http.Get** to a variable but always i try it the values when comes is *undefined*

```
TesteToken() : any {
let token;
this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/token`).subscribe(res => {
  token = res;
  return token;
});}
```

but when i put this

```
 TesteToken() : any {
let token;
this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/token`).subscribe(res => {
  token = res;
  console.log(token);
});}
```

then works and the output is in console

Comment: Don't forget that your HTTP GET call is **asynchronous**. Generally speaking, it is code smell to "flatten" an Observable into a local variable in this way, for the very reasons you're having problems. Consider consuming the Observable as an Observable, possibly implementing a BehaviorSubject architecture (or a library like NgRx) to be able to "store" values in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution (convert obserbable to promise and add async/await):

```
async TesteToken(): Promise<Something> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/token`).toPromise();
}

let token = await  this.TesteToken();
```

Comment: you need to add `await` before this.TesteTokens(); or you just save Promise to `token` variable, and you can use `await` only inside of async functions.

Comment: and you probably face this issue in the future if you go this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092083/async-await-in-angular-ngoninit

Comment: Subhana Allah ,Thanks  a lot Souhail HARRATI ,it's so useful and helpful brother

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: You are trying to return async response, like its synchronous.

```
    TesteToken() : any { // this does not return anything since function ends before a value is returned.
    let token;
    this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/token`).subscribe(res => {
      token = res;
      return token;  // does nothing
    });
}
```

**Fix**: Subscribe where you want to set the value.

```
TestToken() : Observable<any> { // you can set the type of any
return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/token`);
}
```

To access the value;

```
// code runs
    this.TestToken().Subscribe((value) => { 
// code runs after value has returned from server
console.log(value); 
})
// code outside subscribe runs first without waiting.
```

Comment: there´s no difference the problem persists, the console log is showing and the value is not  set

Comment: if the code runs after the value has returned from server why i can set the value to variable?
 let token;
    this.service.ObterToken().subscribe((data) => token = data);
    console.log(token);

Comment: `token = data` should be 'this.token = data', if you are trying to access that data outside subscribe, It should be a property, not a variable

Comment: same result adding a property to get data value

Comment: how are you viewing the data value? FYI, you will get the value when the response comes from the API, if you want to suppose call a function after the value is set, that function will also have to do inside the subscribe.

Comment: The code is fine I would suggest you to read , the link , You seem to lack understanding of this concept https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-in-javascript/