# Async Filtering of an array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm trying to filter an array with values of another array to avoid duplicates in array 1.

Example:
I have an object that has tags (array) and an array of tags that are available. Now I want to remove the indices from "available" to avoid to have available indices which are always tagged at the object.

```
availableTags: Tag[]
actualTags: Tag[]

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.actualTags = this.config.data.actualTags
    this.messageId = this.config.data.messageId
    this.tagService.getAllTags().subscribe({
      next: (tags) => {
        this.availableTags = this.filterAvailable(tags, this.actualTags)
        console.log(this.availableTags)
      }
    })
  }

  filterAvailable(tags: Tag[], actual: Tag[]) {
    return tags.filter((tag) => !actual.includes(tag))
  }
```

My problem now is, that the init process of angular is faster than the filter function (so `this.availableTags` is empty). How can I wait for my filter?

Comment: Faster than your filter? I don't understand. You subscribe to your service. If it become the data the subscribe method will call then your filter. You can add a loading spinner or set a variable if loading to true in progress to the start of ngOnInit and to false in subscribe-next.

Comment: you can make your filteravailable function promise or observable that can help

Comment: @Flo The filtered list is filled with all items although it should contain only 2 items, because they are in the other array

Comment: Includes the Tag array JS objects like {id: xx,....}? Then includes will not work. Eventually is this the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474585/337128 - You could try with async/await